# How I get WI-FI SSID using broadcast receiver programmatically?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Currently when I start my app, one SSID is shown.
But if I change WI-FI, SSID is also gets changed,
I want to know, how do I get WI-FI SSID in broadcast receiver by programming?

I want to SSID broadcast receiver example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` broadcast receiver

Like :

```
    if (WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals (action)) {
        NetworkInfo netInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra (WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if (ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI == netInfo.getType ()) {

         if(netInfo.isConnected(){

             WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService (Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
             WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo ();
             info.getBSSID ();
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand part.    (then check for netInfo.isConnected() and use ) what mean ?    perhaps example possible? sorry.;

Comment: (WifiManager) getSystemService (Context.WIFI_SERVICE);     >> change context.getSystemService                                    and netIndo  global variable?

Comment: sry typo its netinfo

Comment: I'm beginner , so I not use github.     can you read for my code?my code is not working.   please your mail  (my code very simple)